# Need suggestions about a Facebook analytics system

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a small project which will basically do some Facebook stuff and pulls the new daily like for client's pages into my database so I could show them my own charts with their page statistics. Now first of all, I have made a [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) request running with a cron-job and scraping their `Total Likes` every day using the simple graph-api URL.

The problem is with `New Daily Likes` / `Daily unlikes` because, based on my little research, there is no way to access these without having a valid `access_token` and doing `today total - yesterday total` is not exactly correct, because it will confuse the new likes with the people who disliked this and it will be a total mess.

I don't want to force my clients to go to Facebook and get an access token to access the insights for 2 reasons: 1) I want it to be totally `non-technical` so they will not need to mess too much with tokens and stuff outside of my panel. 2) I bet some of them will have problems with storing their access tokens in my database.

How do I do that so they will only need to give me the ID of their page (that's how it currently works and I don't want to change it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 ways to get Likes information, one is to query public information, like:
http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

And the other one is to query for page insights information, for which you need access tokens with right permissions.

If you don't want your clients to install your Facebook application with permissions (and with that, give you access token), your only option is to query public information.

As you've noticed, that gives you a problem, since each day "likes" gain is "mashed up" from users adding likes and removing likes, and thus, you dont have precise information about how many users liked and disliked every day. One way would be to query the information, lets say per hour, or even 5 minutes, and store that information. Then, by simple math, you can see how many users liked and disliked the page. It is still not totaly precise, but its alot more valid than "daily information".